# getting time zone name from offset in moment.tz

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, utc, moment-timezone

I have a api which needs to store a utc+timestamp in mongodb. I am trying to save the value in mongodb which is saving in UTC time. While retreiving i am trying to send the current time using the below code

```
return moment.tz("2022-02-04T08:19:38Z","Asia/Seoul").format()
```

The above code is working fine. Now i have a use case as the input format will be

```
2022-02-04T08:19:38Z+09:00
```

I need to get the timeZone from the offset above likeif i pass +0900 i need output as "Asia/Seoul",Any idea as how can I proceed forward? Kindly help

Comment: Check this

https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/651

Comment: @AayushMall Thanks but i am unable to get the output from the mentioned function any idea as how to proceed?

Comment: Maybe it is time to move to [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/zones) or [dayjs](https://day.js.org/en/)

Answer (score 1):

String `2022-02-04T08:19:38Z+09:00` is not valid. `Z` indicates UTC time while `+09:00` indicates UTC offest, i.e. you provide a timestamp with two (different) time zones.

As it is ambiguous I cannot propose a solution. Is `2022-02-04T08:19:38` intended to be UTC or Seoul time?

This one would work:

```
moment("2022-02-04T08:19:38+09:00").format()
```

MongoDB stores date values as UTC time - **always and only!** If you need to preserver the input time zone, then you have to store it separately in an extra field.

Comment: Hi thanks for the ans. I will have a input as utctime+offset which i will have to store in mongodb and when retrieving will have to be in same format. My issue here is mongodb is changing the above value into a utc time and saving. I am unable to get the user time since i will not know the timezone but only the off set value ie +0900

Comment: This above solution is converting the time based on my local time where the output is 2022-02-04T04:49:38+05:30 where as i need the time of ASIA/SEOUL

Comment: Try `moment("2022-02-04T08:19:38+09:00").tz("Asia/Seoul")` Using `moment("2022-02-04T08:19:38+09:00").tz("+05:30")`  does not work at mentioned in comment above.

Comment: Yup that works . The thing is i will not know "Asia/Seoul" will have only the offset that is +0900. That is why i am asking if there is any way to get the name "Asia/Seoul" from "+0900"

Comment: Certainly not, see how many countries/regions use [UTC+9](https://24timezones.com/time-zone/utc+9)

Comment: Yeah I am stuck here and dont know to proceed further. Basically i want to store the time as utc+offset via nodejs mongoose to mongodb and when retrieving should display the correct calculated time based on utc+offset.  Can you tell me a best approach as how to proceed?

Comment: Be aware `UTC+09:00 != "Asia/Seoul"` in case of Daylight Saving Times! Also `UTC+09:00` is **always** 9 hours before UTC whereas timezone given by IANA name may change, see for example [Asia/Singapore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singapore_Standard_Time)